# Creating a struct object for a linked list from my own static library

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list

I'm creating a c++ library that will contain multiple operations on data structures.I got it to work with arrays and now with linked list im kinda lost.
Here is the code from the library:

```
namespace LinkedList {
struct Node {

    int data;
    struct Node* next;
}*first = nullptr;




class Linked_List {
    public:
        static void Create(int arr[], int n);
        static void Display(  Node* ptr);
    };
}
```

------this is the implementation------

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "framework.h"
#include "Alchemia.h"
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include <iostream>

namespace LinkedList {

    void Linked_List::Create(int arr[], int n)
    {
        int i;
        struct Node* t, * last;
        first = new Node;
        first->data = arr[0];
        first->next = nullptr;
        last = first;

        for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            t = new Node;
            t->data = arr[i];
            t->next = nullptr;
            last->next = t;
            last = t;
        }
    }

    void Linked_List::Display(  Node* ptr)
    {
        while (ptr != NULL)
        {
            std::cout << ptr->data << std::endl;
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here is what i have for the main testing program,

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "Alchemia.h"
    #include "LinkedList.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    struct Node {
        int data;
        struct Node* next;
    }*first;

    int main()
    {
    //---------------LINKED LIST OPS

    Node node = Node();
    Node* q = new Node[];
    int arr2[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0 };
    LinkedList::Linked_List::Create(arr2, 10);
    LinkedList::Linked_List::Display(q);//error is here




    return 0; 

}
```

Now matter what i try i keep getting the error: argument of type node is incompatible with parameter of type "LinkedList::Node"

Comment: You have defined two types called "Node". (On a side note, exposing the linked list's node type to its users is going to cause you no end of problems.)

Comment: You also have two variables called "first", and `LinkedList` is just a quasi-class. Only being able to use one linked list in an entire program doesn't make for a very useful library.